# XSD Schema of the ODL language

Tags: xml, xsd

I came across a problem here and don't know where to start.  I desperately need help with this. Here's what I want.

I need to write an XSD Schema, to represent the ODL language.

As we know the structure of ODL, there are interfaces/classes, that can extend others, they may have attributes, relationships, operations. Each of them has their options and preferences.
The XSD should represent the structure of ODL with all its possible properties.

Can anyone give me some help with this? How should I do it? Will appreciate anything...

**EDIT1:**
Ok, did my own research and got where to start. Here is my start point. I already have defined the part that declares the class/interface in ODL.

Now, need to find out what and how to write inside the "odlType" `complexType`. That should include all possible properties (attributes, relationships). Am I right?

**EDIT2**
Ok, now I added the attributes of class but don't know if I need to do something in case the attribute type is a Set or List...
Here is my last achievement... and for now, my question is, what to do with attributes? Is this enough, or I must change the "attrType"?

**EDIT3** All right. Changed the "attrType" a little. Now I thing it's applicable for more complex types. But what if the attribute is a class type? And I still don't know what to do with relationships... please give me a hand with this...

**EDIT4** Changed a little to include extending of classes. Not sure if this method is correct. But anyway.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ODL"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="odlType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="attribute" type="attrType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="reference" type="refType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="objType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="odlSubType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="odlType">           
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="objType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="class"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="interface"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="attrType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="attr" type="attrType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="preType" type="preType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="preType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Struct"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Enum"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Now thinking about relationships of ODL. I think I better add them as sequence of attributes of "odlType". But just don't know what types to give them.... Oh please give me a hand... I desperately need advice on this...

Comment: Sorry, but it's not at all clear what you want to achieve.

>>I need to build an XML Schema (XSD) to validate any XML which is the conversion of some ODL.<<

ODL is a data description language. The paper you cite gives rules for converting an ODL schema into an XML schema (XSD). Are you saying that having done this conversion, you now want to convert the object database (described by the ODL schema) into an XML instance (described by the XSD schema)? That doesn't seem to be what you are asking. Sorry, you've got me stumped.

Comment: I have improved my post, I think now it's more understandable :)

Comment: Isn't there anyone with any help??? Or is it still not clear what's the problem?

Comment: One hard part is the possibility to extend classes in ODL. Is my solution to use base type and `xs:extent` correct?

Comment: OK, now I wonder if I should keep the references in a seperate complexType... Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first learn what XSD is and how to author XSD documents. I suggest you read the below two tutorials in the given order

1. [w3schools basic XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/)
2. [zvon complete tutorial](http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/series.html)

and then read

[Mapping Rules to Convert from ODL to XML-SCHEMA](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/mathkour/XML%20DB/Mapping%20Rules%20to%20Convert%20from%20ODL%20to%20XML-SCHEMA%20where%20is%20the%20subsequent%20work%20of%20this.pdf)

Comment: 1. I am familiar with XSD. 2. the mapping rules won't help, because they're about mapping the given db. I need to build xsd for the ODL language structure...

Comment: @ArVan then what is you question?

Comment: As I've said, I need help with building the XSD for ODL Language. Not a single ODL db.
PS. see my edit on the post. Have already started with the class definition. Next step is class attributes...

Comment: @ArVan class attributes can either be an element inside "odlType" or an attribute of "odlType". Search" when to use element and attribute in xml" in google

Comment: I think the class attributes should be attributes of "odlType". Because they have types and values and other properties... they can even be complex types... The tough part would be referencies...